# Flutter custom actions in AppBar

Tags: flutter, dart

In order to have the same AppBar through my whole application, I created a separated file containing the AppBar which I include in every screen. It is also possible to pass some variables e.g.: actions. So for different screens I can have different actions still within the same AppBar. All this works fine like shown in the code below. But how to hide the Actions in the AppBar when there are no actions passed (`dropdownChoices.length == 0`)?

```dart
class BaseAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final Color bgColor = HexToColor('#508bbb');
  final String title;
  final AppBar appBar;
  final TabBar tabBar;
  final List<DropdownChoices> dropdownChoices;
  final bool isHomepage;
  final bool goBack;

  final PageRouteBuilder _homeRoute = new PageRouteBuilder(
    pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _, __) {
      return HomePage();
    },
  );

  BaseAppBar(
      {Key key,
      this.title,
      this.appBar,
      this.tabBar,
      this.dropdownChoices,
      this.isHomepage = false,
      this.goBack = false})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ...
      actions: <Widget>[
        PopupMenuButton<DropdownChoices>(
          onSelected: (value) {
            if (value.action == 'refresh') {
              Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, value.route);
            }
          },
          elevation: 6,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
            return dropdownChoices.map((DropdownChoices choice) {
              return PopupMenuItem<DropdownChoices>(
                value: choice,
                child: Text(choice.title),
              );
            }).toList();
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class DropdownChoices {
  const DropdownChoices({this.title, this.action, this.route});

  final String title;
  final String action;
  final String route;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be inclined to try something like

```dart
actions: (dropdownChoices.length < 1) ? null : <Widget>[
  PopupMenuButton<DropdownChoices>(...),
],
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of **collection `if`** to exclude list items based on a condition:

```dart
actions: <Widget>[
  if (dropdownChoices.length != 0) PopupMenuButton<DropdownChoices>(...),
]
```

This should solve your problem as the action will not be included when you provide an empty list of `dropdownChoices`.
If `dropdownChoices` can be `null`, you should check for null in your condition as well.